# Como rodar um video do Vimeo na tag video

Tags: html, html5, vídeo, vimeo-api

Preciso rodar uma video do Vimeo na tag video, como fazer?
Encontrei isso aqui:

```
<video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"></video>
```

Rolou de boa, mas esse não é meu video, alguém sabe explicar? Ou como que gera essa URL?

Answer (score 1):

Facinho.
é só ir em compartilhar video e copiar o link na área de incorporar o video. Depois adicionar no html do seu site.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso precise mesmo utilizar a tag video, baixe o mp4 através de um site como o  [save from net](https://pt.savefrom.net/11-como-baixar-vimeo-v%C3%ADdeo.html)

olha o exemplo que fiz em 10 segundos no sublime text 3.
[image: olha o exemplo que fiz em 10 segundos no sublime text 3.]

Answer (score 0):

Bem, o Vimeo não permite que você tenha acesso a esse vídeo bruto(.MP4), mas você pode consegui-lo facilmente apenas inspecionando a página com o navegador e retirando o trecho de código responsável pelo vídeo.

Como por exemplo o vídeo abaixo que retirei do site oficial do vimeo, apenas inspecionando o elemento e copiando o trecho de código.

```html
<video controls autoplay preload="" src="https://01-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/4863/2/74317104/189249795.mp4?expires=1505088239&amp;token=0ea4e3812d7a0bf4aa0bb"></video>
```

Caso esteja utilizando o Google Chrome, faça como o exemplo desse print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.